# Nucleo32 with STM32F303K8 crashes when setting PA2 as Interrupt and triggering it

Tags: arduino, stm32, interrupts, nucleo

I am using a [nucleo 32](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-f303k8.html#documentation) for my project. I am using arduino and creating a TCP modbus and RTU modbus server.
I have set the pins as folows:

| Description | Type | Arduino | STM32 | Pin Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pulse input 1 | INTERRUPT | A0 | PA0 | 6 |
| Pulse input 2 | INTERRUPT | A1 | PA1 | 7 |
| Pulse input 3 | INTERRUPT | A7 | PA2 | 8 |
| Pulse input 4 | INTERRUPT | A2 | PA3 | 9 |
| Pulse input 5 | INTERRUPT | A3 | PA4 | 10 |
| Pulse input 6 | INTERRUPT | A4 | PA5 | 11 |
| Pulse input 7 | INTERRUPT | A5 | PA6 | 12 |
| Pulse input 8 | INTERRUPT | A6 | PA7 | 13 |
| MAX31865 DI | MOSI | D6 | PB1 | 14 |
| MAX31865 DO | MISO | D3 | PB0 | 15 |
| MAX31865 CLK | CLK | D9 | PA8 | 18 |
| MAX31865 CS 1 | OUTPUT | D10 | PA11 | 21 |
| MAX31865 CS 2 | OUTPUT | D2 | PA12 | 22 |
| MAX31865 CS 3 | OUTPUT | D5 | PB6 | 29 |
| MAX31865 CS 4 | OUTPUT | D4 | PB7 | 30 |
| MODBUS RTU TX | TX | D1 | PA9 | 19 |
| MODBUS RTU RX | RX | D0 | PA10 | 20 |
| DEBUG Serial TX | TX | -- | PA14 | 24 |
| Ethernet W5500 CS | OUTPUT | -- | PA15 | 21 |
| Ethernet W5500 SDI | MOSI | D11 | PB5 | 28 |
| Ethernet W5500 SDO | MISO | D12 | PB4 | 27 |
| Ethernet W5500 SCK | CLK | D13 | PB3 | 26 |
| Ethernet W5500 RST | NRST | -- | NRST | 4 |
| SWDIO | SWDIO | -- | PA13 | 23 |
| SWCLK | SWCLK | -- | PA14 | 24 |

I have set the Serial as folows:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <ArduinoRS485.h>
#include <ArduinoModbus.h>
#include <Adafruit_MAX31865.h>

/* Modbus RTU UART setup */
HardwareSerial Serial1(PA10, PA9);
RS485Class ModbusRS485(Serial1, PA9, -1, -1);

// Use software SPI: CS, DI, DO, CLK
Adafruit_MAX31865 thermo = Adafruit_MAX31865(PA12, PB1, PB0, PA8);
// The value of the Rref resistor. Use 430.0 for PT100 and 4300.0 for PT1000
#define RREF 400.0
// The 'nominal' 0-degrees-C resistance of the sensor
// 100.0 for PT100, 1000.0 for PT1000
#define RNOMINAL 100.0

byte mac[] = {
    0x80, 0x20, 0xE1, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xE};

// Default to use W5100. Must change to false for W5500, W5100S, for faster SPI clock
#define USE_W5100 false

/**
 * @brief The pins used for the pulse interrupts.
 */
const int interruptPin1 = PA0;
const int interruptPin2 = PA1;
const int interruptPin3 = PA2;
const int interruptPin4 = PA3;
const int interruptPin5 = PA4;
const int interruptPin6 = PA5;
const int interruptPin7 = PA6;
const int interruptPin8 = PA7;

uint16_t interruptNumber = 0;
unsigned long previousTime = micros();

uint16_t interruptNumber1 = 0;
uint16_t interruptNumber2 = 0;
uint16_t interruptNumber3 = 0;
uint16_t interruptNumber4 = 0;
uint16_t interruptNumber5 = 0;
uint16_t interruptNumber6 = 0;
uint16_t interruptNumber7 = 0;
uint16_t interruptNumber8 = 0;

unsigned long previousTime1 = 0;
unsigned long previousTime2 = 0;
unsigned long previousTime3 = 0;
unsigned long previousTime4 = 0;
unsigned long previousTime5 = 0;
unsigned long previousTime6 = 0;
unsigned long previousTime7 = 0;
unsigned long previousTime8 = 0;

EthernetServer ethServer(502);

ModbusTCPServer modbusTCPServer;

ModbusTCPServer modbusTCPServer1;

EthernetClient client1;
bool client1_connected = false;

EthernetClient client2;
bool client2_connected = false;


void setup()
{
  Serial.setTx(PA14);
  Serial.setRx(PNUM_NOT_DEFINED);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("");
Ethernet.init(PA15);

  Serial.print("Initializing ethernet... ");
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("failed");
    bool isW5500 = (Ethernet.hardwareStatus() == EthernetW5500);
    Serial.print(F("Ethernet type is "));
    Serial.println(isW5500 ? F("W5500") : F("W5100"));
    if (Ethernet.hardwareStatus() == EthernetNoHardware)
    {
      Serial.println("Ethernet shield was not found.  Sorry, can't run without hardware. :(");
    }
    else if (Ethernet.linkStatus() == LinkOFF)
    {
      Serial.println("Ethernet cable is not connected.");
    }
  }
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());


  ethServer.begin();

  Serial.print("Initializing pulse inputs... ");
  pinMode(interruptPin1, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(interruptPin2, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(interruptPin3, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(interruptPin4, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(interruptPin5, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(interruptPin6, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(interruptPin7, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(interruptPin8, INPUT_PULLUP);

  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin1), interrupt1Callback, FALLING);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin2), interrupt2Callback, FALLING);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin3), interrupt3Callback, FALLING);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin4), interrupt4Callback, FALLING);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin5), interrupt5Callback, FALLING);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin6), interrupt6Callback, FALLING);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin7), interrupt7Callback, FALLING);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin8), interrupt8Callback, FALLING);

  Serial.println("ok");

  // start the Modbus TCP server
  Serial.print("Starting modbus TCP server 1... ");
  if(!modbusTCPServer.begin(1)) {
    Serial.println("failed");
    return;
  }
  
  modbusTCPServer.configureHoldingRegisters(0x00, 100);
  Serial.println("ok");

  Serial.print("Starting modbus TCP server 2... ");
  if(!modbusTCPServer1.begin(2)) {
    Serial.println("failed");
    return;
  }

  modbusTCPServer1.configureHoldingRegisters(0x00, 100);
  Serial.println("ok");

  Serial.print("Configuring modbus serial... ");
  Serial1.begin(115200);
  if(!Serial1) {
    Serial.println("failed");
  } else {
    Serial.println("115200 baud");
  }

  Serial.print("Starting modbus RTU server 1... ");
  if(!ModbusRTUServer.begin(ModbusRS485, 3, 115200)) {
    Serial.println("failed");
    return;
  }
  ModbusRTUServer.configureHoldingRegisters(0x00, 100);
  Serial.println("ok");

  Serial.print("Initializing RTD inputs... ");
  if(!thermo.begin(MAX31865_2WIRE)) {
    Serial.println("ok");
    return;
  }

  Serial.println("failed");
}

void handle_connect()
{
  EthernetClient client = ethServer.accept();

  if(client) {
    if(!client1_connected) {
        client1 = client;
        client1_connected = true;
        modbusTCPServer.accept(client1);
        return;
      } else if (!client2_connected) {
        client2 = client;
        client2_connected = true;
        modbusTCPServer1.accept(client2);
        return;
      }

    client.stop();
  }
}

void handle_modbus()
{
  ModbusRTUServer.poll();
  if(client1.connected()){
    modbusTCPServer.poll();
  }

  if(client2.connected()){
    modbusTCPServer1.poll();
  }

  if(!client1.connected() && client1_connected){
    client1_connected = false;
    client1.stop();
  }

  if(!client2.connected() && client2_connected){
    client2_connected = false;
    client2.stop();
  }
}

unsigned long last_temp_reading = 0;

void handle_temp()
{
  if (millis() - last_temp_reading <= 1000)
  {
    return;
  }

  uint16_t rtd = thermo.readRTD();
  float ratio = rtd;
  ratio /= 32768;
  Serial.print("Temperature = ");
  Serial.println(thermo.temperature(RNOMINAL, RREF));

  // Check and print any faults
  uint8_t fault = thermo.readFault();
  if (fault)
  {
    Serial.print("Fault 0x");
    Serial.println(fault, HEX);
    if (fault & MAX31865_FAULT_HIGHTHRESH)
    {
      Serial.println("RTD High Threshold");
    }
    if (fault & MAX31865_FAULT_LOWTHRESH)
    {
      Serial.println("RTD Low Threshold");
    }
    if (fault & MAX31865_FAULT_REFINLOW)
    {
      Serial.println("REFIN- > 0.85 x Bias");
    }
    if (fault & MAX31865_FAULT_REFINHIGH)
    {
      Serial.println("REFIN- < 0.85 x Bias - FORCE- open");
    }
    if (fault & MAX31865_FAULT_RTDINLOW)
    {
      Serial.println("RTDIN- < 0.85 x Bias - FORCE- open");
    }
    if (fault & MAX31865_FAULT_OVUV)
    {
      Serial.println("Under/Over voltage");
    }
    thermo.clearFault();
  }

  last_temp_reading = millis();
}

void loop()
{
  handle_connect();
  handle_modbus();
  handle_temp();
}

void interrupt1Callback()
{
  interruptNumber1++;
  modbusTCPServer.holdingRegisterWrite(0x00, interruptNumber1);
  unsigned long currentTime = micros();
  int pulseTime = int((currentTime - previousTime1) / 10);
  previousTime1 = currentTime;
  modbusTCPServer.holdingRegisterWrite(0x20, int(pulseTime / 100));
  modbusTCPServer.holdingRegisterWrite(0x21, pulseTime & 0xFFFF);
  modbusTCPServer1.holdingRegisterWrite(0x20, int(pulseTime / 100));
  modbusTCPServer1.holdingRegisterWrite(0x21, pulseTime & 0xFFFF);
  ModbusRTUServer.holdingRegisterWrite(0x20, int(pulseTime / 100));
  ModbusRTUServer.holdingRegisterWrite(0x21, pulseTime & 0xFFFF);
}

void interrupt2Callback()
{
  interruptNumber2++;
  modbusTCPServer.holdingRegisterWrite(0x01, interruptNumber2);
  unsigned long currentTime = micros();
  int pulseTime = int((currentTime - previousTime2) / 10);
  previousTime2 = currentTime;
  modbusTCPServer.holdingRegisterWrite(0x22, int(pulseTime / 100));
  modbusTCPServer.holdingRegisterWrite(0x23, pulseTime & 0xFFFF);
  modbusTCPServer1.holdingRegisterWrite(0x22, int(pulseTime / 100));
  modbusTCPServer1.holdingRegisterWrite(0x23, pulseTime & 0xFFFF);
  ModbusRTUServer.holdingRegisterWrite(0x22, int(pulseTime / 100));
  ModbusRTUServer.holdingRegisterWrite(0x23, pulseTime & 0xFFFF);
}
void interrupt3Callback()
{
  interruptNumber3++;
  modbusTCPServer.holdingRegisterWrite(0x02, interruptNumber3);
  unsigned long currentTime = micros();
  int pulseTime = int((currentTime - previousTime3) / 10);
  previousTime3 = currentTime;
  modbusTCPServer.holdingRegisterWrite(0x24, int(pulseTime / 100));
  modbusTCPServer.holdingRegisterWrite(0x25, pulseTime & 0xFFFF);
  modbusTCPServer1.holdingRegisterWrite(0x24, int(pulseTime / 100));
  modbusTCPServer1.holdingRegisterWrite(0x25, pulseTime & 0xFFFF);
  ModbusRTUServer.holdingRegisterWrite(0x24, int(pulseTime / 100));
  ModbusRTUServer.holdingRegisterWrite(0x25, pulseTime & 0xFFFF);
}
void interrupt4Callback()
{
  interruptNumber4++;
  modbusTCPServer.holdingRegisterWrite(0x03, interruptNumber4);
  unsigned long currentTime = micros();
  int pulseTime = int((currentTime - previousTime4) / 10);
  previousTime4 = currentTime;
  modbusTCPServer.holdingRegisterWrite(0x26, int(pulseTime / 100));
  modbusTCPServer.holdingRegisterWrite(0x27, pulseTime & 0xFFFF);
  modbusTCPServer1.holdingRegisterWrite(0x26, int(pulseTime / 100));
  modbusTCPServer1.holdingRegisterWrite(0x27, pulseTime & 0xFFFF);
  ModbusRTUServer.holdingRegisterWrite(0x26, int(pulseTime / 100));
  ModbusRTUServer.holdingRegisterWrite(0x27, pulseTime & 0xFFFF);
}
void interrupt5Callback()
{
  interruptNumber5++;
  modbusTCPServer.holdingRegisterWrite(0x04, interruptNumber5);
  unsigned long currentTime = micros();
  int pulseTime = int((currentTime - previousTime5) / 10);
  previousTime5 = currentTime;
  modbusTCPServer.holdingRegisterWrite(0x28, int(pulseTime / 100));
  modbusTCPServer.holdingRegisterWrite(0x29, pulseTime & 0xFFFF);
  modbusTCPServer1.holdingRegisterWrite(0x28, int(pulseTime / 100));
  modbusTCPServer1.holdingRegisterWrite(0x29, pulseTime & 0xFFFF);
  ModbusRTUServer.holdingRegisterWrite(0x28, int(pulseTime / 100));
  ModbusRTUServer.holdingRegisterWrite(0x29, pulseTime & 0xFFFF);
}
void interrupt6Callback()
{
  interruptNumber6++;
  modbusTCPServer.holdingRegisterWrite(0x05, interruptNumber6);
  unsigned long currentTime = micros();
  int pulseTime = int((currentTime - previousTime6) / 10);
  previousTime6 = currentTime;
  modbusTCPServer.holdingRegisterWrite(0x2A, int(pulseTime / 100));
  modbusTCPServer.holdingRegisterWrite(0x2B, pulseTime & 0xFFFF);
  modbusTCPServer1.holdingRegisterWrite(0x2A, int(pulseTime / 100));
  modbusTCPServer1.holdingRegisterWrite(0x2B, pulseTime & 0xFFFF);
  ModbusRTUServer.holdingRegisterWrite(0x2A, int(pulseTime / 100));
  ModbusRTUServer.holdingRegisterWrite(0x2B, pulseTime & 0xFFFF);
}
void interrupt7Callback()
{
  interruptNumber7++;
  modbusTCPServer.holdingRegisterWrite(0x06, interruptNumber7);
  unsigned long currentTime = micros();
  int pulseTime = int((currentTime - previousTime7) / 10);
  previousTime7 = currentTime;
  modbusTCPServer.holdingRegisterWrite(0x2C, int(pulseTime / 100));
  modbusTCPServer.holdingRegisterWrite(0x2D, pulseTime & 0xFFFF);
  modbusTCPServer1.holdingRegisterWrite(0x2C, int(pulseTime / 100));
  modbusTCPServer1.holdingRegisterWrite(0x2D, pulseTime & 0xFFFF);
  ModbusRTUServer.holdingRegisterWrite(0x2C, int(pulseTime / 100));
  ModbusRTUServer.holdingRegisterWrite(0x2D, pulseTime & 0xFFFF);
}
void interrupt8Callback()
{
  interruptNumber8++;
  modbusTCPServer.holdingRegisterWrite(0x07, interruptNumber8);
  unsigned long currentTime = micros();
  int pulseTime = int((currentTime - previousTime8) / 10);
  previousTime8 = currentTime;
  modbusTCPServer.holdingRegisterWrite(0x2E, int(pulseTime / 100));
  modbusTCPServer.holdingRegisterWrite(0x2F, pulseTime & 0xFFFF);
  modbusTCPServer1.holdingRegisterWrite(0x2E, int(pulseTime / 100));
  modbusTCPServer1.holdingRegisterWrite(0x2F, pulseTime & 0xFFFF);
  ModbusRTUServer.holdingRegisterWrite(0x2E, int(pulseTime / 100));
  ModbusRTUServer.holdingRegisterWrite(0x2F, pulseTime & 0xFFFF);
}
```

I have removed the SB2 solder brige from the NUCLEO.
Now 7 of the 8 inputs work as expected except PA2 (A7). Whenever this pin is triggered the program stops working.
I would like to know why this pin is causing a crash?
Could somebody explain why this is happening?

The external interrupt line for PA2:
[image]

And the chip connections where you can see that PB2 is connected to ground, PB2 is on the same interrupt line here is the image:
[image]

Comment: You might have better luck at arduino.se, as this is more about how to use arduino than hardware problem.

Comment: Also the posted code does not show what you do in the interrupt callback. You might be doing things not allowed in interrupt. And that interrupt may do something different compared to other interrupts. If you want an answer what might be wrong, you should at least tell what you do in then code so we could even have a look what might be the problem.

Comment: The PA2 pin is normally used as the TX pin of the UART2. I have changed the TX pin to PA14.  ```Serial.setTx(PA14);
  Serial.setRx(PNUM_NOT_DEFINED)``` As seen in the code above. And then changed the pinmode to OUTPUT. @Justme Could this have something to do with the interrupt vectors of this chip?